# Why doesn't BasicHttpBinding need a Principal Name to use Kerberos Auth on IIS7?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I know a fair amount about how Kerberos Authentication works, but for the life of me I can't explain a strange behavior I am seeing with an IIS-hosted WCF service.

I've set up an extremely simple WCF app that exposes an endpoint using BasicHttpBinding with TransportCredentialOnly. My understanding is that for Kerberos to work, a User Principal Name or Service Principal Name must be specified by the client. For some reason it doesn't seem consistent across different binding types.

When I omit this principal name, on IIS6, NTLM ends up being used. On IIS7, it uses Kerberos. 
When I specify a User Principal Name on IIS6, Kerberos is used but on IIS7 the calls fail (Wireshark shows an KRB_AP_ERR_BADMATCH error during the Kerberos handshake).

It gets even more fun when I switch the binding to WSHttpBinding with Message security. In that experiment if I don't specify the User Principal Name on IIS6 the call fails, and on IIS7 NTLM gets used. When I specify the UPN, IIS6 fails and II7 ends up using Kerberos. Here's a summary of my findings. If anyone out there can help me wrap my mind around what's happening, I'd be eternally grateful.

[image: Summary table]

Answer (score 2):

Do you know about kernel-mode authentication in IIS 7?  It removes the need to use a custom identity for the application pool, and it also (in most cases) removes the need to assign SPNs to the custom identity or host machine.

[Here's a blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webtopics/archive/2009/01/19/service-principal-name-spn-checklist-for-kerberos-authentication-with-iis-7-0.aspx) that describes when you need to set SPNs when using kernel-mode authentication.

Comment: Ahh, thats a fascinating read. Thanks @John - this might be exactly what is causing the differences between IIS6 and IIS7. I'll experiment around with disabling Kernel Mode authentication and see what effect that has. I'll come back and update this as the answer if so.